# rosserial_server wifi connection Raspberry pi ESP8266

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

This post is related to ROS (Robot Operating System) and ESP8266, and has also been cross-posted on [ROS Answers](https://answers.ros.org/question/361530/rosserial_server-wifi-connection-raspberry-pi-esp8266/) and [Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/21152).

I've ROS Melodic running on a Raspberry Pi 4 and need to send out information (as strings) over wifi to multiple ESP8266. I'm only just starting so it's just one ESP8266 for now. For communication, I'm using `socket_node` found in the ROS package `rosserial_server` (package [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_server#socket_node)).

Referring to the picture below, the slave node publishes to the topic `/Topic_data_over_wifi` which is subscribed by a node running on the ESP8266:
[image: pictures from rqt_graph]

The problem is, the node `/rosserial_server_socket_node` remains ***floating***!

I've double checked names of topics and IP addresses, and at one point, got the node `/rosserial_server_socket_node` to actually link to the rest of the ROS network as shown in the "What I want" section. However, that was just one time (a fluke?) and never could I again get `/rosserial_server_socket_node` to join the ROS network.

`rosserial_server`'s `socket_node` is used with its default settings (port 11411). I did try other port numbers but there was no difference. After all nodes have been launched, here's the output of `rostopic list` (other than the usual */rosout* and */rosout_agg*):

- */commands_from_master_node*
- */topic_data_over_wifi*

**Goal: I need to find a way to connect the ESP8266 and the Raspberry pi 4 over wifi using ROS.** More specifically, I need to get data from the slave node (on Raspberry Pi) to the node running on the ESP8266.

I've already looked at this [multiple-TCP-connections](https://answers.ros.org/question/274159/multiple-tcp-connections-using-rosserial_server-with-wifi-arduino/) post but didn't find anything that could solve my problem.

Any inputs/suggestions will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the software running on the ESPs, it might be an option to use the [ROS MQTT bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/mqtt_bridge). The downside is that you will need an additional MQTT broker (I am not sure, but as I recall mqtt_bridge is an MQTT client and requires a broker like [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/)). You can add MQTT clients to the ESPs and connect them to the same broker and subscribe to MQTT messages. In other words, you create a MQTT network for the ESPs with their borker and add ROS to that network, via mqtt_bridge. If you are not running ROS specific software on the ESPs it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, MQTT did help me achieve what I wanted. However, would you have any idea why `rosserial_server socket_node` doesn't work? I like to use as few "external tools" as possible and now I've to use MQTT pub-sub for this singular purpose while I already have another pub-sub system well set up!

Comment: No sure why it did not work Have you iried this https://github.com/agnunez/espros

Comment: I did come across it, but I think that's for single connection only (is that right?). I'll eventually need to connect to multiple ESP8266's, so I didn't really try it out.